# tsc resolves types from a different package version

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-resolution, type-resolution

We have a monorepo using pnpm workspace, and multiple services are using the `graphql` package, with different versions.

Trying to compile one service using `tsc --explainFiles`, I get this:

```
../../node_modules/.pnpm/apollo-link@1.2.14_graphql@15.3.0/node_modules/apollo-link/lib/index.d.ts
  Imported via 'apollo-link' from file '../../somewhere/in/project.ts' with packageId 'apollo-link/lib/index.d.ts@1.2.14'
  File redirects to file '../../node_modules/.pnpm/apollo-link@1.2.14_graphql@14.7.0/node_modules/apollo-link/lib/index.d.ts'
```

And the compilation fails due to type mismatches.
Why is this redirection? I checked, and there is no symlink between these files or directories.
`tsc` already resolved the correct dependency, why redirect to another one?

Checked all versions in `package.json`, and everything seems to be ok.
When adding to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
    "*": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

It fixes the problem, but I have no idea why this prevents the redirect, and what are other implications this might have.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears that `pnpm` creates a `node_modules` directory inside `.pnpm` folder by default, hoisting all the dependencies from monorepo there. If some dependency references another package, but doesn't have a direct dependency listed in package.json, typescript will resolve actual file in `.pnpm` directory and will go up until it finds the dependency in `.pnpm/node_modules` with most common version in monorepo. This behavior causes problems for me and can be changed with `hoist-pattern`. Still, turn off the hoisting creates more problems